# Mediawiki add user from custom registration page

Tags: php, apache, mediawiki

I set up a custom registration page to my http server (apache) which hosts a number of services, including a wiki.
The intended goal is to have the user sign-up at once to all these services including the wiki of course.

For the wiki I'm trying to rearrange the "CreateAndPromote" maintenance script and fit it into my page. By now I came up with this snippet

```html
$path = "/wiki";
putenv("MW_INSTALL_PATH={$path}");
require_once ("/wiki/includes/WebStart.php");
chdir("wiki");

$mediaWiki = new MediaWiki();


$name = $_POST['username'];
$pass = $_POST['password'];


$user = User::newFromName( $name );


if ( !is_object( $user ) ) {
 die("Invalid user!\n");
}

$exists = ( 0 !== $user->idForName() );

if ( !$exists ) {
  $user->addToDatabase();
} 

  
try {
 $user->setPassword( $pass );
 

} catch ( PasswordError $pwe ) {
 die("password error:" . $pwe->getText()."");
}


$user->addGroup("editor");
$user->saveSettings();

$ssu = new SiteStatsUpdate( 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 );
$ssu->doUpdate();
```

But i get

```
Error: LightnCandy class not defined
```

MediaWiki   1.25.2
PHP     5.6.12 (apache2handler)

Comment: The easier way to do this would be to use the API: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Account_creation

Comment: thanks for pointing me to the apis, but in cases like mine mediawiki itself suggest to use WebStart.php in order to call MediaWiki classes and functions directly https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Client_code#PHP

Comment: The solution for class not defined errors is usually running Composer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was simple as that:
declaring the MW_INSTALL_PATH like that apparently did not work

```
$path = "/wiki";
putenv("MW_INSTALL_PATH={$path}");
require_once ("/wiki/includes/WebStart.php");
```

so I had to change dir to the wiki BEFORE requiring the webstart.php

```
chdir("wiki");
require_once ("/includes/WebStart.php");
```